# What is the situation with land border crossings on the Georgia-Azerbaijan border?

Tags: covid-19, borders, georgia-country, azerbaijan

Azerbaijan has extended its Special Quarantine Regime until January 2. I have been led to believe that the land border restrictions of the Special Quarantine Regime prevent any travel to Azerbaijan from neighboring countries via land borders. Is this true? Is it possible to enter Azerbaijan via land borders such as the Georgian-Azerbaijani border before January 2 2024, or only by air?

https://www.turan.az/ext/news/2023/9/free/Social/en/9045.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We call it Regime, without "Special Quarantine" crap. So, indeed our Regime has been extended until January 2, 2024, which means our land borders (including Georgia-Azerbaijan border) will be closed at least until then.

I've [read](https://x.com/cavidaga/status/1706290686608175567?s=20) that foreigners can leave the country via land border, but no one's allowed to enter via land.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing @gdrt

Comment: Sure, hope you can afford a plane ticket.